# Connecting java to MYSQL database in an amazon server

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, socketexception

I am trying to connect my java code with mysql DB in amazon ***rds***, i am using this code:

```
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://HOST:port_number/DB_name","DB_username", "DB_pass");
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table name WHERE id = 1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DB error : " + e);
    }
```

i am getting this error when i run it :

```
DB error : java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to any hosts due to exception: java.net.SocketException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at DB.<init>(DB.java:15)
at subgroup.main(subgroup.java:72)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

any ideas !!

Comment: Try to ping the DB server URL and check if your are able to do so

Comment: i updated my ans as it not a url as mush its a **HOST** as i am using amazon _RDS_ , dk if that will make any difference, i tried to ping it but the result was `request timed out.`  @NikhilTalreja

Comment: looks like you machine does not have access to your DB server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give access to your machine from where you are trying to read the database.

Also you should grant access to your IP using command prompt.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

i rephrase your command because you set the `connection` variable as drivermanager but in your statement you use `con`?
and the string inside the connection replace it with the real value for example

```
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "<your DBUsername>", "<your DB Password>");
```

dont just copy paste next time, learn how the codes work

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://HOST:port_number/DB_name","DB_username", "DB_pass");
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table name WHERE id = 1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DB error : " + e);
    }
```

Comment: that was just a typing mistake here only , thanks anyway

Comment: @AhmadBassiouny ohh i see, and let me know if you still need help im willing to solve this problem :)

Comment: well , i am still having the same problem :)

Comment: @AhmadBassiouny can you send your actual coding? and i will correct it if i can :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was using a connection from emulator to localhost.
If you use emulator to localhost dont use localhost,127.0.0.1 in connection String but use:

10.0.2.2

Hope this helps